# Why do we have to call getCurrentUser() several times Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am creating a Journal app.

I am currently working on the functionality for if the user is already logged in—bypass the "get started/log in activities"

In the video I am watching to create a journal app, the instructor calls
`mUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();` several times.

He calls it in `onStart()`, in `onCreate()` and in `onAuthStateChanged()`. I can understand why we might need to call it again in `onAuthStateChanged()`, but in this case, I'm just checking if the user is already logged in, so it shouldn't change from the user received in `onCreate()`

I removed it from `onAuthStateChanged()` and `onStart()` and everything is still working fine. However, I'm unsure if it will lead me to errors in the future. If anyone can confirm this, I would appreciate it.
**Is there a reason why we need to call `getCurrentUser()` several times?**
Thanks.

This is my full code for reference:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button getStarted;

    private FirebaseUser mUser;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener myListener;
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference myCollectionRef = db.collection("Users");


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();




        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getStarted = findViewById(R.id.btnGetStarted);

        getStarted.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        });

        myListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull @NotNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if(mUser != null){
                    //logged in
                    
                    //I commented this out and everything is still working fine
                    //mUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    String currentUserId = mUser.getUid();

                    myCollectionRef.whereEqualTo("userId", currentUserId).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onEvent(@Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                            if(error != null){
                                Log.d("my_error", error.toString());

                            }

                            if(!value.isEmpty()){
                                for(QueryDocumentSnapshot snapshot : value){
                                    JournalApi myJournalApi = new JournalApi();
                                    myJournalApi.setUsername(snapshot.getString("username"));
                                    myJournalApi.setId(snapshot.getString("userId"));

                                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, JournalList.class));

                                    finish();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    //not logged in
                }
            }
        };


    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        //I commented this out and everything is still working fine
        //mUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(myListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if(firebaseAuth != null){
            firebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(myListener);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While signing in is an active process, that your code triggers by calling one of the `signInWith` methods, maintaining the authentication state and restoring it on application restart are background processes that happen automatically when you use the Firebase SDK. This is great, because it means you don't have to write code to keep tokens valid, or to check if the user profile has changed or their account has been disabled.

It does mean however that you can't reliably cache the  value of `firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()` in a variable for much time. If you keep the value in a variable, and then the SDK updates the authentication state in the background, your code may not be looking at the correct value for `firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()` anymore.

That's why you'll see more calls to `firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()` than you might expect, and also why you'll see `firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener` in places that want to get notified when the authentication state changed, like when the user is signed in or out by the SDK.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Why is it necessary to get the current user in onCreate() and onStart() though? Can't we just check for the current user in onAuthStateChanged() (which will included all the processes like signing in, signing out, etc.)? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, in general I prefer using auth state listeners for all but the initial value. Since your code has to have some default value, I tend to use `getCurrentUser()` for that in `onCreate` as that reflects the current value when that code executes.

Comment: Thanks. But the onStart() is unnecessary, correct?

Comment: It depends a bit. Theoretically the `onAuthStateChanged` might fire later, as it could be that the SDK is (in the background) determine the initial state. The SDK prevents it from firing before the initial check is done, so there might be a "period of unknown state" in there. But initializing the current user to `null` there is going to be the same as actually checking it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still a little confused though. Why would currentUser be null if I say mUser = getCurrentUser(); in onStart() --even if it gets fired before onAuthStateChanged? Thanks.

Comment: Because Firebase may still be checking the credentials/status in the background. If you check before that is done, current user will be null. And `onAuthStateChanged` will only fire once the check is completed.

Comment: So when we call getCurrentUser(), does Firebase internally call onAuthStateChanged()? Thanks.

Comment: No it doesn't. It's more like the other way around. The background code that modifies the current user, also calls any auth state change listener.

Comment: Oh, I see. So the SDK will check the credentials in the background + modify the current user and then once finished(if any change occurred) call onAuthStateChanged? If we don't override onAuthStateChanged, will it do anything automatically after being invoked? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You've to call this method everytime you want to check the user's current session due the user's session can be changed from another service or method, if you don't call this method and just call once, you won't have the latest user's profile info, auth session, and such more.